# ng-repeat dynamic data not showing while tags are available

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to pull content from my website through JSON. I have successfully called it and even tags are showing properly. The only issue I am facing is the list is not displaying.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
module.controller('FiveReasons', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $sce) {
ons.ready(function() {
                console.log("Inside 5 Reasons");

                //$scope.spinner = true;
                   var reasonsListing = $http.get("http://vbought.com/design_14/index.php/design_ci/post/Clients");
                    reasonsListing.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data[0].post_title);

                        $scope.reasonsLists = data;

                        $scope.spinner = false;
                    });
                    reasonsListing.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        alert("Can Not load the address Ajax");
                    });

    });
});
```

I feel like list need to be refreshed after ng-repeat is completed. But I am not sure how can I do it in Angular.

Here is how I called this.

```
<ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen var="carousel" name="FiveRes" class="FiveRes">      

<ons-carousel-item style="background: #09a4c0;" ng-repeat="reasonsList in reasonsLists"  bn-log-dom-creation="with">
        <div class="item-label">Number</div>

      </ons-carousel-item>


      <ons-carousel-cover></ons-carousel-cover>
    </ons-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment original posts yet so I'll just do this here. What does `reasonsLists` look like? Is your carousel displaying anything at all (looking at your code, it should display `"Number"` as many times as the length of `reasonsLists`)?

Otherwise, if you wanted to display, for instance, the `post_title` of each entries in `reasonsLists` instead of `Number`, then replace:

```html
<div class="item-label">Number</div>
```

by:

```html
<div class="item-label">{{reasonsList.post_title}}</div>
```

Comment: Actually the output is working. But the list is not refreshing like we do in jquery "triger("refresh")"